# how can I get my Python 3.6 back after installing Tornado 4.5.3?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I use `miniconda` to run `Python 3.6`. Everything was fine until I couldn't start Jupyter notebook. The error message was:

```
File "/Users/usr/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
from notebook.notebookapp import main


File "/Users/usr/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 45, in <module>
    ioloop.install()
  File "/Users/usr/miniconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 210, in install
    assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \
AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'
```

After a Google search, I tried the following:
`conda install tornado=4.5.3`
But it gave a warning message:

```
CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a 2.7.x release that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
```

But I didn't read carefully so I performed it anyway. Now I can open Jupyter notebook, but my Python was downgraded to `2.7` How can I get my `Python 3.6` back?! :'(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't edit my own question, but here is the package I downloaded from the command: The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    tornado-4.5.3              |           py27_0         596 KB
    ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1 |           py27_2          10 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         606 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ssl_match_hostname: 3.5.0.1-py27_2

Comment: `conda install`ing a package shouldn't downgrade your python install. How are you starting Jupyter? Also, the path `/Users/usr/...` is a pretty big red flag, as `usr` should sit in `/` or `root`

Comment: Thank you @C.Nivs. I changed my name to usr for privacy concern. each usr should be my name. I type "jupyter notebook" from Terminal to start it.

Comment: @C.Nivs My jupyter notebook only gives me the option of creating a new Python 2 notebook option when I click New. My old scripts can't run in this environment because I wrote them in Python 3.

Comment: You will want to [create a miniconda environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) with a python 3.6 install. Then you should be able to `source activate <your env>` and pip install Tornado that way

Comment: I think the issue is that miniconda is just reverting to a python2.7 base install, so creating a 3.6 env and activating it should resolve the issue, and you can install to that environment after it's activated

Comment: if you open terminal and type `python --version` what do you get? (python 3 might still be there, it can co-exist with 2.7 ; also try `python3 --version`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Thanks to @C.Nivs and @Feelsbadman. Here is my solution:

- I checked my python environment by: `conda env list` and found out I have a base, a 2.7 and a 3.6 environments existed at the same time, with the base being the default.
- I activated my 3.6 env by `source activate py36`
- I created an ipython kernel by `conda install notebook ipykernel` then `ipython kernel install --user`
- Open jupyter notebook, now there is a Python 2 and Python 3 kernel.

I will try to remove the Python 2 from jupyter notebook since I don't use 2.

Thank you for the help.